# String encoding VB6 / C++ dll

Tags: c++, vb6

I am having a problem with some characters in 2 strings that my program uses.

String #1 is filled using VB code that gets data from a 3rd party application.
String #2 gets similar data from the same 3rd party application, but it gets it with a C++ dll and sends it to VB.

The data has some weird symbols in it.

I don't know a whole lot about encoding and different character sets, but I'll try to explain it the best I can.

I will use "Т" as my example character.

"Т" (note this isnt a normal capital t) it is unicode decimal value 1058
http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x0422/index.html

When this character appears in String #1 during runtime it appears as "?", which I believe is just what VB6 does to show some unicode characters.  When I use AscW on the character it returns the correct value of 1058.

When I output the string to a text file, it appears as "?".

The same character in String #2 from the C++ DLL appears as 2 characters "Ð¢"

When I output that string to a text file, the character appears properly as "Т".

I was only outputting things to text files for testing purposes.  I only need the 2 strings to be encoded / appear the same during run time.

Any idea whats going on here?  Any way for me to get weird characters to appear the same in both strings?

Thanks

edit:  also the C++ dll is in multi character set and sends the data in a BSTR string

CODE IN C++ DLL

allChat is a CString

```
BSTR Message;
int len = allChat.GetLength();
Message = SysAllocStringByteLen ((LPCTSTR)allChat,len+1);
```

Message is returned to the VB app.. and nothing happens to the string after that.

String #1 is just a regular VB string

Comment: This sounds like UTF8 you are getting in C++

Comment: Can you expand on that?  Does the String that is filled from the C++ dll sound like UTF8? 

If so, should I figure out how to convert it once in VB or should I do something in the C++ dll before it sends the data?

Comment: Show some code, what is the type of your c++ string

Comment: C++ data is originally in a CString

it is converted to BSTR before being sent to VB like this

 edit: ill add code to OP

Comment: Show some code, I cannot answer before that

Comment: added more info to OP

i have to step away from the computer for a bit, so I will reply to any more questions you have when I get back

Comment: You can't safely store non textual data in a VB6 string. It goes through various character set encoding methods when being passed out of VB's control. If the text is truely text then you'll need to confirm exactly what encoding is used, and when passed as a string, make sure it really is a wide unicode string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the way Cyrillic "T" becomes "Ð¢", you get your string as a UTF8 encoded string (I verified that with Notepad++ by switching encodings). You need to convert it to Unicode before sending it to your VB app. Note that your VB app needs to be Unicode, not ASCII.

You can convert UTF8 to std::wstring with this function:

```
std::wstring utf8to16( const char* src )
{
    vector<wchar_t> buffer;
    buffer.resize(MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, src, -1, 0, 0));
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, src, -1, &buffer[0], buffer.size());
    return &buffer[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks satuon, I think this is enough info to get me heading in the right direction :)

Comment: You can use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) to convert, see my edit

Comment: Perfect thanks!

I won't have a chance to try it until tomorrow, so I will just accept your answer now :).  I am pretty sure if I have any problems I can take it from here anyways.  

Thanks for the help!